# How to loop through elements with a specific class name in selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, webdriver

There are a dynamic number of div containers on the page with the class name 'sponge', I need to loop through these and then get details from each one, but I can't figure out how to do this. This is what I've tried so far...

```
const containers = await driver.findElements(By.className(`sponge`))

for(let t = 0; t < containers.length; t++){
  let runner = await containers[t].findElement(By.xpath(`//div[2]/div[1]/div/p`)).getText()
  console.log(runner)
}
```

When I do this I just get the 'runner' in the first 'sponge' class container x amount of times, with x being the length of 'contaniers'. It doesn't actually find the 'runner' that is in the contanier I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the immediate `child node` for `parent node` you need to use `.` try now.

```
const containers = await driver.findElements(By.className("sponge"))

for(let t = 0; t < containers.length; t++){
  let runner = await containers[t].findElement(By.xpath(".//div[2]/div[1]/div/p")).getText()
  console.log(runner)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed!!!!

Answer (score 0):

- i suggest you to use another way to scraping this website you can try modules like `request`, `got`, `axios`, `node-ferch` they will send a http request to the page and will getting back you the page html then you can use a module like `jquery-jsdom` to get the dom object of the response element then you can access anything you wants to by jQuery selectors.
- scraping to extract data is better by http request

Comment: Is this better though for download amounts? wouldn't the download sizes be a lot higher?

Comment: Size of what? you need just to one of them you can use `request`, `jquery-jsdom`

Comment: No I mean the download amounts for the things that are being scraped, would it be better for the download sizes if I got the entire html of the page and then manipulated that in node? or if I just scraped the parts of the page that I need?